# How to use ngStorage for multiple forms in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

How to store multiple form data in local storage, I am trying to store multiple forms data in local storage in angular js. i tried following code:

```
 <form name="welcome">
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData.field1' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData.field2' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData.field3' />
    </form>
    <form name="registration">
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData2.field1' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData2.field2' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData2.field3' />
    </form>
    <form name="sendMail">
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData3.field1' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData3.field2' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData3.field3' />
    </form>
    <script>
    myApp.service('dataService',function(){

       var cache;

       this.saveData = function(data){
          cache = data;
       };

       this.retrieveData = function(){
          return cache;
       };

    });
    myApp.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, dataService){

       dataService.saveData($scope.pageData);

    });

    myApp.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, dataService){

       $scope.pageData = dataService.retrieveData();

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: No problem with your code but it can store only one pageData each time. If you want to store multiple forms, You need to modify your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testapp" >
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <form name="welcome">
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData1.field1' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData1.field2' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData1.field3' />
    <input type="button" value="welcomeBTn" ng-click="welcomeTo(pageData1);" />
    </form>
 </div>
 <div  ng-controller="Ctrl2">
   <form name="registraitonForm">
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData2.field1' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData2.field2' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData2.field3' />
    <input type="button" value="regBTn" ng-click="registration(pageData2);" />
    </form>
    </div>
 <div  ng-controller="Ctrl3">
   <form name="mailToForm">
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData3.field1' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData3.field2' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='pageData3.field3' />
    <input type="button" value="mailBtn" ng-click="mailTo(pageData3);" />
    </form>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">


var app = angular.module('testapp', []);
    /*main controller at index page*/
app.service('dataService',function(){

   var self = this;

   self.saveData = function(key, data){
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
   };

   self.retrieveData = function(key){
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
   };
   return self;

});
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, dataService){
  $scope.welcomeTo = function(pageData1){ 
   dataService.saveData('page1', pageData1); //  like this pass the key of the value to be stored in local storage

  }
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, dataService){
  $scope.registration = function(pageData2) {
   dataService.saveData('page2', pageData2);
   console.log($scope.pageData2) //  like this pass the key of the value to be stored in local storage
  }
});


app.controller('Ctrl3', function($scope, dataService){

  $scope.mailTo = function(pageData3) {
  dataService.saveData('page3', pageData3);
  console.log($scope.pageData3)//  like this pass the key of the value to be stored in local storage
   console.log(dataService.retrieveData('page1'))
  }
});


</script>

</body>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/kmBA3Cco8QNDL8i4eOjz?p=preview working plunker for you.

Comment: dataService.saveData($scope.pageData); here we storing welcome form data that $scope.pageData but other forms like registration $scope.pageData2 and $Scope.pageData3 how can i do?

Comment: can you show me in jsfiddle or plnkr, I tryed but still it is not coming

Comment: There actually the data is replacing everytime. Wait I will change

Comment: CHARAN CHERRY CAN YOU SHOW ME ONCE IN JSFIDDLE?

Comment: I added plunker and see console message and go to Application->LocalStorage->https://run.plnkr.co to see the saved value

Comment: i clicked on run.plnkr.co but it is page not find, please check once

Comment: Bro, I didn't say click on that. I said go to its location. Open plunker I provided in my answer. Press F12, go to Application->Local Storage. There u will see run.plnkr.co This is my plkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/kmBA3Cco8QNDL8i4eOjz?p=preview

Comment: charan i asked multiple form data , how to store in localstarage (angular js)

Comment: please see this link once  https://plnkr.co/edit/PizQ4AKc0IEVYz4QuRlO?p=preview ,

Comment: You did something not correct in your plunker. I did for one, You have to do it for all

Comment: actualy i am getting in multiple form data storing in localstorage problem here only, that is the reson i kept question here please help

Comment: page1, page2 , page3 values stored but it all seperate rows , how can i store single object

Comment: page1, page2 , page3 values stored but it all seperate rows , how can i store single array object

Comment: In that case you need to store them all in an array first and then push it to the storage. But that is not correct. Better to have individual form data to avoid future problems. Because, if you stored in a single array and you just want to call a single form data, in that case you need to call all forms data. It is your wish